# change color of the tab control panel background

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

I have a `TabControl` like so:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding TabItems, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                    SelectedIndex="0" 
                    BorderThickness="0" 
                    TabStripPlacement="Left"
                    Padding="10,0,0,10">
            <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                                <Grid Name="Panel">
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ContentSource="Header" Margin="20,5"/>
                                </Grid>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background" Value="#d9534f" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                                        <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background" Value="#E6E3DB" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header, Mode=OneTime}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Content, Mode=OneTime}"/>
                </Style>
            </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </TabControl>
```

Is there a way to change the color of the `Panel` where `TabItems` are located:

[image]

Thank you for any suggestions.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT after OP clarified the question.**

The are you refer to has nothing to do with the `TabItem` or even the `TabControl`. It's simply the control where the `TabControl` resides in.

Please see the following simple example:

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflowWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackOverflowWPF"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="300">
    <Grid Background="LightSeaGreen">
        <TabControl Background="Red">
            <TabItem Header="Tab1" Background="Yellow">
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Tab1" Background="Green">
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And this is what it looks like in the designer:

[image]

So going back to your example, I'm assuming you want to set the color of area pointed to by an arrow, while keeping the rest of the form in a different color. I'd make use of the `Grid` control for that.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="LightGreen">
        <TabControl Grid.Row="0" Background="Red" Height="100">
            <TabItem Header="Tab1" Background="Yellow">
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Tab1" Background="Green">
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

And it will look like this:

[image]

Comment: you missed my point completely. I am asking about setting the TabItem Panel color so the background color around/behind tabs themselves. I don't want to set the content background color. My image above is a vertical tab item control so content is to the right and tabs will be stacked on the left.

Comment: It's that bit of code that matters: TabStripPlacement = "Left" ....you missed that I guess.

Comment: What are you referring to by _TabItem Panel_? Which part of the `TabItem` do you want to change the background color of?

Comment: Is it the area to the right of two `TabItem` headers in my example?

Comment: Please see my edit....and yes, that's the area to the right of the headers in your example. In my example it's the area below the headers.

Comment: OK, then your question is misleading, because that area has nothing to do with the `TabItem` controls. It's simply the control whatever the `TabControl` resides in. So you want to change background color of that control. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: got it! that was the tip I was looking for. So in my case, it's inside of the grid. Changing grid background will fill out that color. Thanks!

Comment: Edited the answer. You can have even more control of the color by using a grid inside a grid as I've pointed out.